# Using Promise.all() to upload multiple images to AWS s3. How to handle error where only one image fails to upload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload multiple images to an s3 bucket using signed URLs. The flow is that the front end app sends a GET request to the server to get a signed url for each image to be uploaded. The front end app then uses the signed urls to upload the images directly to the s3 bucket.

My question is how would I handle the case where one image fails to upload?

For example, if I want to upload three images, and one of them fails to upload, would I have to delete the other two images from the s3 bucket before having the user attempt to upload the files again?

```js
/*
 * @param {array} images: Array of objects of shape ({image: object, signedUrl: string})
 * 
 */

const uploadImages = (images) => {
    const axiosPutPromises = images.map(({ image, signedUrl }) => {
      const putFile = () => axios.put(signedUrl, image, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": image.type
        }
      });
      
      return putFile();
    });
    
    try {
      const res = await axios.all(axiosPutPromises);
      // dispatch res to redux store

    } catch (err) {
      /*Not sure how to handle error where only one files fails to upload*/
    }
```

Comment: axios.all uses Promise.all under the hood. Promises.all is all or nothing. It resolves once all promises in the array resolve, or reject as soon as one of them rejects. In other words, it either resolves with an array of all resolved values, or rejects with a single error.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @AnshulBansal

Answer (score 1):

I've not used axios, but the way I handled this in a project using regular Promises that I'm working on was avoid to rejecting.

So I catch any errors in the per-job Promise, and then accept the Promise with a structured value that lets me distinguish success from failure. You can then inspect the array returned by `Promise.all()` and do whatever error handling you want there.

Answer (score 0):

axios.all uses Promise.all under the hood. Promises.all is all or nothing. It resolves once all promises in the array resolve, or reject as soon as one of them rejects. In other words, it either resolves with an array of all resolved values, or rejects with a single error.

Your use case should be handled this way by default.

Comment: I just tried this out where I uploaded an empty object to one of three signed urls (where the other two files are valid images) to invoke a promise reject. When I checked the s3 bucket, it seems like the other two files were uploaded successfully, even though the Promise.all was rejected.